# Sitecore 8.1 How to extend Experience Profile

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-xdb, experience-editor

I'm currently tracking the visitors of the website. I've added a new facet and the information is being added to MongoDB. 
I thought that the experience profile would pick this new info but apparently not. I tried to find a way of showing this facet but what I've found so far seems way too complex. https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/03/15/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-experienceprofilecontactviews/
Anyone found any good documentation on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: It is relatively a lot of work, no short way seen so far.

Comment: As the Experience Profile is SPEAK based and data is retrieved via Pipeline processors and reports you have to go through the same steps as the OOTB facets. The two posts of mine cover everything you need to do, there isn't a shortcut unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with tight deadlines so I'm afraid I'll skip this for now. Thanks for your replies. @JonathanRobbins thanks for all the sharing in your blog.

Comment: Old post, info may no longer be valid, and may not be any less complicated than the link already mentioned, but take a look at https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/using-custom-contact-data-part-1-experience-profile

Comment: Thanks @AdamConn. I came across your post as well when I was investigating.. I reckon that the steps described are similar. It seems a lot of work to achieve what I wanted. Given that is not a MUST on this project, I'll try to implement later on. Will update you guys if I find any other (shorter) way of doing this.